# DB2, several count lines with a group by statement

Tags: sql, db2

I have a pretty simple query in db2 that returns 3 different conditional counts, each as a value:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS current_year,
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE -  1 YEAR
                          BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS prior_year,
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE('2018-12-31') - 7 DAY
                          BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS full_year
FROM newData n
WHERE n.customer = 111
```

Which works fine and currently returns something like:

```
current_year | prior_year  |  full_year
---------------------------------------
412             562             613
```

The problem is, I want to group them by certain conditions but it no longer returns the one result set, rather a lot of result sets each with their own count:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS current_year,
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE -  1 YEAR
                          BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS prior_year,
    IFNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE('2018-12-31') - 7 DAY
                          BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                      THEN 1 END), 0) AS full_year
FROM newData n
WHERE n.customer = 111
GROUP BY color,category
```

So rather than a count of every line I'd like to get a count of the groupings (basically lowering each number/count but still only result set)

Is there something that i'm missing to properly do this with?

UPdate:

An example -

If I have the following rows

```
product  |  color  |  category  |  start_date  |  expire_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
1            Red        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
2            Red        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
3            Red        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
4            Blue        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
5            Blue        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
6            Blue        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
7            Green        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
8            Green        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
9            Green        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
10           Green        Leather   '2018-12-01'    '2018-12-31'
```

So if they all fall within a certain date range, say prior_year, then I would want that count to be 3 instead of 10

If I did a select similar to above

```
select
    ifnull(count(case when '2018'12'15' between start_date and expire_date then 1 end),0) as LastYear
from newData
group by color,category
```

I would expect:

```
lastYear
--------
   3
```

Comment: Still not clear.  You haven't shown the _output_ you want from that table.  What do you want to see here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen does the newest update help at all? I'm just trying to make sure that each count for the respective date range is counting by group and not rows. So above, there are only 3 distinct groups (Red leather,blue leather and green leather) and that's what i want back from the count. If I were to just select all grouped by that it would return 3 rows, but each with counts. I want ONE row, with groupng counts

Comment: Try my answer below and if not what you want, then comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try aggregating twice here, once to find the groups which meet your requirements, and the second to take the total counts over all groups.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        detail1,
        detail2,
        detail3,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                   THEN 1 END) AS current_year,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN CURRENT DATE -  1 YEAR BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date
                   THEN 1 END)AS prior_year,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE('2018-12-31') - 7 DAY
        BETWEEN n.start_date AND n.expire_date THEN 1 END) AS full_year
    FROM newData n
    WHERE n.customer = 111
    GROUP BY
        detail1,
        detail2,
        detail3
)

SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = current_year THEN 1 END) AS current_year,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = prior_year   THEN 1 END) AS prior_year,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN cnt = full_year    THEN 1 END) AS full_year
FROM cte;
```

Comment: See that's kind of my issue, i don't really want to select the actual details, I just need the three counts based on the date ranges. Say there are three records a piece for the colors red, green and blue. Right now I'm returning 9 rows, but if I group by color I would want to only return 3

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.  Add sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I added a sample of beginning data and what I would expect the resulting count to be

Comment: You're a lifesaver, that worked perfectly! Thank you... This helps me to see how to do multiple aggregations in the future though, rather than relying on a direct count

Comment: May I ask that next time you follow a certain pattern when asking data questions on this site?  _Always_ show the sample input, expected output, and describe the logic to get from start to finish.  This helps to make transparent what you are asking.